# When trying to remove headbob from the players camera, "FPSPlayerCamera" errors out

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using MelonLoader;

namespace GoodbyeHeadbob
{
    public class HeadbobBeGone : MelonMod
    {
        float bobbingAmount = 0;
        float bobbingHorizontalAmount = 0;
        public override void OnSceneWasInitialized(int buildindex, string sceneName)
        {
            // Find the players camera, and set the bobbing amount to 0.
            FPSPlayerCamera camera = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectOfType<FPSPlayerCamera>();
            camera.bobbingAmount = 0;
            camera.bobbingHorizontalAmount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Error is "The type or namespace name 'FPSPlayerCamera' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
I'm trying to make it where there is 0 headbob on the camera, I've tried generating a class for it but still had to luck with stopping the error, since making it a class caused more errors.

Comment: What is the `FPSPlayerCamera` type and where is it defined? In which file and in which namespace?

Comment: Gonna be honest chief, the code I've posted is the whole file. I'm not the most experienced in C# but I was under the impression that the float's was defining it.

Comment: It's calling `FindObjectOfType` to locate an object of type `FPSPlayerCamera`.  That's not a built-in class or one that is provided with Unity in any way.  It looks like it may belong to a custom script.  What inspired you to write this code referring to a class that doesn't exist?  Did you download this code from somewhere or follow a tutorial or something?  It looks like you are missing a key component of your solution, which is this `FPSPlayerCamera` class/script.

Comment: I got support from the support team on Melonloader, and a bit of the code I got help from `Github Co-Pilot`.

Answer (score 0):

If the `fpsplayercamera` class is inside a namespace, can you try searching it again as `FindObjectOfType<Namespacename.FPSPlayerCamera>()`?

Comment: Just tried that, still errors out.
1 - FPSPlayerCamera cannot be found.
2 - FPSPlayerCamera does not exist in the namespace 'GoodbyeHeadbob'

Comment: Would you try to  public define FPSPlayerCamera on the HeadBobBeGone Class.
Like:
public FPSPlayerCamera fpsCamera;
and fill it manually with drag and drop on inspector then try access fpsCamera variable. Im just trying to detect your problem ^^

Comment: Tried adding that, errored out. I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or what, I'm sorry :((